# How do I access the sending textbox inside an 'onfocus' function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given the following HTML and function:

```
<input type="text" onfocus="TextBoxFocus()" id="txtName" />
```

.

```
function TextBoxFocus()
{

}
```

Is it possible to get the id of the calling textbox from inside the function?

Thanks 
Kevin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change just a bit your html

```
<input type="text" onfocus="TextBoxFocus(this)" id="txtName" />
```

And here you go:

```
function TextBoxFocus(self) {
    var id = self.id
}​
```

Answer (score 1):

Just pass `this` as an argument of the handler:

```
onfocus="TextBoxFocus(this)"


function TextBoxFocus(textbox)
{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass this obj. See below,

```
//<!--                   Passing this obj---v                 -->
<input type="text" onfocus="TextBoxFocus(this)" id="txtName" />
```

And in script,

```
function TextBoxFocus(obj)
{
    alert(obj.id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did a [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/WgNDW/5/) and this seems to work:

`<input type="text" onFocus="onFocus(this)" />`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to use it for many textboxes, so i am giving a `class` selector

```
<input type="text"  id="txtName1" class="someTextBox"/>
<input type="text"  id="txtName2" class="someTextBox"/>
```

Script

```
$(function(){

  $(".someTextBox").focus(function(){
     var txtID=$(this).attr("id");
     alert(txtID);
  });

});
```

Jsfiddle sample : http://jsfiddle.net/MLH4p/